I am getting this error my Flutter project in Android Studio
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

Could not find method implementation() for arguments [androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

I change my classpath and sdk version
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'

}
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

above the code my build.gradle file

I am not an expert in Android.
But from what I'm seeing, it looks like this -
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
}

section should be inside your, $PROJECT_ROOT/android/app/build.gradle file. But you've added it in your $PROJECT_ROOT/android/build.gradle file.
There are 2 build.gradle file.

App level build.gradle. Which belongs to the android/app/ folder/directory!
Project level build.gradle. Which belongs inside the android directory!

So maybe, removing this section from here. And moving to the bottom of your App level build.gradle file. And adding the implementation line to the dependency section. Might solve your problem.
